# PDF to Excel in Java

Tags: java, itext, apache-poi

I'm converting data from PDF to excel. PDF contains table. I used Itext- pdf to read the data  & with the help of apache poi covert it to excel.But everything is convert as text even table row & columns. I like to write table as row & columns as it like in PDF so Kindly help me to read table in PDF to write into Excel.

**Here is my code:**

```
PdfReader reader;
try {
    reader = new PdfReader("D:/JDEV_WORK/MANOJ/ItemPriceReport.pdf");
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    TextExtractionStrategy strategy;
    String line = null;
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        strategy = parser.processContent(i,new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
        line = strategy.getResultantText();
        System.out.println("line --- "+line);
    }

//conversion starts here....

HSSFRow myRow = null;
HSSFCell myCell = null;
CreationHelper helper = myWorkBook.getCreationHelper();
List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(new StringReader(line));

for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    String str[] = lines.get(i).split(",");
    myRow = mySheet.createRow((short) i);
    for (int j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
    myRow.createCell(j).setCellValue(helper.createRichTextString(str[j]));
   }
}



        FileOutputStream fileOut;
        try {
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:/JDEV_WORK/MANOJ/ItemPriceExcel.xls");
            myWorkBook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND");
        }
    reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand the two up-votes. You're not even telling us if your PDF is a Tagged PDF or not. If not, then the open source version of iText won't help you. You'll need a closed source iText add-on such as [pdf2Data](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdf2Data) and you'll need to *teach* the system how to detect tables if your document doesn't contain any *real* tables. It's not because *you* see a table that there is a table; if your PDF isn't tagged, **then there is no table** when a *machine* looks at the PDF.

Comment: I don't know much about the PDF whether it is Tagged PDF or Not. It is open sourced version only. You mean in closed source itext add on such as pdf2Data will help to detect tables in pdf. Then kindly how to  get closed source one.If you any sample source kindly send the link.

Comment: You can open the PDF in Adobe Reader and look at the Document Properties to see if the PDF is a Tagged PDF. As for pdf2Data, I already provided a link, but you probably overlooked it: https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdf2Data

Answer (score 5):

That makes perfect sense if you understand a little bit about PDF.
PDF is not a wysiwyg format. It's more a container of instructions than a container of human-readable content.

Internally a PDF file looks something like this

> go to coordinate 50, 50
>   use font Helvetica Bold
>   set font size to 12
>   draw the glyph for character 'H'
>   go to coordinate 56, 50
>   draw the glyph for character 'e'

That being said, it is ridiculously hard to revert this unstructured data back to a sensible table.

Answer (score -1):

For Ubuntu (Linux) the open source command-line program `pdftotext` is available [http://poppler.freedesktop.org]. You can convert a text-pdf file into its text characters. The output is being written to a file.

The syntax goes:
`pdftotext [options] [PDF-file] [text-file]`

You can easily call `pdftotext` from within Java,
see the following code snippit:

```
String pdfFilenameWithPath = "C:\myPdfFileToParse.pdf"
String cmd = "pdftotext " + pdfFilenameWithPath;
try {
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("pdftotext: cannot run");
    LOG.error("[{}]", e);
}
```

The resulting text-file can subsequently be read by `BufferedReader`,
and further processed within Java.

You need to make simplistic assumptions of the textual format, in the PDF-file. A reasonable conjecture is that the table consists of a label-line, followed by subsequent data-lines. You need to read all these lines into a separate file, in which each field is being separated by ';' (the standard CSV-format). In this intermediate file, you can check that the assumptions you made regarding the table structure in the PDF-file are correct.

The result from the read text-file can be parsed as csv-file. I use Apache's CSV-library for this (org.apache.commons.csv):

```
public List<List<String>> readCSVFile(String filename, boolean bypassHeader) {

    List<List<String>> csvFile = new ArrayList<>();


    try {

        Reader in = new FileReader(filename);
        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = null;
        if (bypassHeader) {
            records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(in);
        } else {
            records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
        }

        for (CSVRecord record : records) {
            List<String> csvLine = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String field : record) {
                csvLine.add(field);
            }
            csvFile.add(csvLine);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("readCSVFile: exception [{}]", e);
    }
    return csvFile;
}
```

Finally, you can **write** the CSV-parsed data into the desired Excel-format, as you already do in the supplied Java-code

Comment: And how would one convert the plain text generated with `pdftotext` to a structured table (distinguish the table header, table rows / columns, table data)? What you are suggesting, the OP is already doing with iText: he gets all the text. The OP is asking for the semantic information of the content.

Comment: I agree. My solution has been extended as to parse the table data.

Comment: Is there any alternative way of converting PDF to HTML and then HTML to Excel.
Is it possible or i need to do two separate workflow like  data --> pdf & data -->Excel.

Comment: Your assumption that the HTML will show the content as tabular data is probably wrong. That is only possible if your PDF is a **Tagged PDF**. Since you don't tell us if your PDF is a **Tagged PDF**, I'm assuming that it isn't, and in that case converting the PDF to HTML, and then the HTML to Excel won't help you.

Comment: My solution partitions the task into less complex steps. Such a strategy is recommended for this kind of advanced data-processing. Being able to inspect the intermediate CSV-file gives you visual feed-back on the result of parsing the textural output of the original PDF-file.

Comment: @FlyingDutchman You don't explain how you go from a plain text file generated from any PDF showing a table to a CSV file. Without that explanation, I am inclined to down-vote your answer. How will you detect a cell that consists of several lines of data?

Comment: An example of the converted PDFtoText is needed as part of this question. Hopefully, @Raj can add to the question, the result of applying `pdftotext` to representative data from his domain.

Comment: @Bruno My PDF is not a Tagged PDF.
In case if it is a Tagged PDF then  PDF -->HTML-->Excel whether it will be possible?

Comment: If a PDF is tagged *correctly*, then a table knows that it's a table. The tags will tell you where to find the header rows and the data rows. The tags will tell you which content belongs to which cell in each row. You won't need HTML if you have all of this information, and all of this information is present in a *properly tagged* PDF. (Note that not all PDF's are properly tagged!)